# Row click in GridView when ViewState is disabled

Tags: asp.net, gridview, viewstate

We are using classic ASP.NET 4. There is a GridView that's causing problems because there is no paging and the ViewState is too large. So, disabling the view state via EnableViewState="False" seemed to solve the problem with the viewstate size, but now I can no longer click on rows. The page refreshes, but the call-back corresponding to CommandName="OpenItem" is not firing.

```
<ItemTemplate>
     <asp:ImageButton
         ID="Id"
         runat="server"
         CommandName="OpenItem"
  />
</ItemTemplate>
```

I tried adding OnClick="ClickHandler" to the ImageButton, but that didn't work either -- the OnClick callback is not firing.

Is there any way, other than adding paging, to have the ViewState disabled and handle clicks on GridView rows?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you disable Viewstate for the entire page, or just that specific GridView control?

Comment: "*...the call-back corresponding to CommandName="OpenItem" is not firing*" - what does this mean, by the way?  Are you handling the GridView's RowCommand event, and it's not being fired?